# Whether creating a windows task scheduler on a running exe will affect the execution process?

Tags: scheduled-tasks

My exe file does few data activities and runs for 3-4 hours. I want to create a Task Scheduler to mention this exe to run on every 3 hours.

I wonder, whether creating a task scheduler on the running exe will affect the process?

Comment: You, probably, should have a special logic to determine whether your process is currently running and then act accordingly.

Comment: Other then exception handling & log tracing, nothing specifically written.

Comment: Can multiple instances of your program run concurrently?

Comment: I have already created Task Scheduler on running exe. I haven't face any impact on doing so. Thank you all.